# Can i make scrollview inside TabView ? because its make a white background in my TabItem

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want make a scrollview inside TabView. but its make a white background color:

[image]

im already add .background in TabView its not work.

this is my code for TabView.

*im using my own Image not systemImage.

```
//  DashboardNavigationView.swift
//  DevMuscles
//
//  Created by Putut Yusri Bahtiar on 05/11/23.
//

import SwiftUI

struct DashboardNavigationView: View {
    
    enum Tab: Int {
        case home
        case insight
        case notifications
        case profile
    }
    
    @State private var selectedTab = Tab.home
    
    @State private var showNotificationDot = false
    
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            HomeView()
                .tabItem {
                    selectedTab == Tab.home ? Image("home-active") : Image("home-inactive")
                }
                .tag(Tab.home)
            
            HomeView()
                .tabItem {
                    selectedTab == Tab.insight ? Image("insight-active") : Image("insight-inactive")
                }
                .tag(Tab.insight)
            
            HomeView()
                .tabItem {
                    selectedTab == Tab.notifications ? Image("notification-active") : Image("notification-inactive")
                }
                .tag(Tab.notifications)
            
            Text("Profile")
                .tabItem {
                    Image("profile")
                }
                .tag(Tab.profile)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    DashboardNavigationView()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is the default background for the tab bar when the selected view has a `ScrollView` that goes behind it.

You can override the visiblity of the tab bar background by using the modifier `.toolbarBackground`. This modifier needs to be applied to the individual view that has the `ScrollView` inside it, not to the parent `TabView`. You can also set a `ShapeStyle` to be used in place of the default background.

Here are some examples that you might like to try:

```swift
HomeView()
    .toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .tabBar)

HomeView()
    .toolbarBackground(.black, for: .tabBar)

HomeView()
    .toolbarBackground(.ultraThinMaterial, for: .tabBar)
```

If you just want to darken the background then you could try setting `.toolbarColorScheme` instead:

```swift
HomeView()
    .toolbarColorScheme(.dark, for: .tabBar)
```

Comment: HomeView()
    .toolbarBackground(Color("bgColor"), for: .tabBar)

i can use like this. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try setting
.accentColor(.desiredColor)

Comment: This changes the color of the selected tab item, but not the color of the background behind the tab items when a ScrollView is active in the selected view.